# How to read the page source?

Tags: product

There's a retail site that uses Magento. Their items sell out super fast so I was wondering if there's a way to generate a permalink with the item codes?

Although that being said I can't even see the product codes when I try to look at the page source.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, each product has a unique identifier called the SKU (Stock Keeping Unit), which is a code that you can use to identify and track products. If you want to generate a permalink with the SKU of the product, you can create a URL rewrite for the product.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Magento admin panel.
2. Go to Marketing > URL Rewrites.
3. Click the "Add URL Rewrite" button.
4. Select "Custom" as the "Create URL Rewrite" option.
5. In the "Target Path" field, enter the path to the product page, which should include the product ID or SKU, for example, /product/12345 or /product/ABC123.
6. In the "Request Path" field, enter the permalink that you want to use for the product, for example, /product-name-12345 or /product-name-ABC123.
7. Save the URL rewrite.

Now, when a customer clicks on the permalink, they will be redirected to the product page with the SKU in the URL. However, note that this will not work if the product page is only accessible when it is in stock. In that case, you may need to create a custom module to generate the permalink dynamically based on the product SKU.

Comment: Ok so I don't own this website though, I'm viewing it as a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

To view the page source of a website as a customer, you can follow these steps:

1. Open a web browser such as Google Chrome or Firefox.
2. Navigate to the website you want to view the page source for.
3. Right-click on the page and select "View page source" or "Inspect" from the context menu. Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+U" (Windows) or "Cmd+Opt+U" (Mac) to open the page source.
4. A new tab or panel will open displaying the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code used to create the page.
5. You can scroll through the code to view the structure and content of the page.